# Insert dates between Date Ranges in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've been searching for quite a while and can't find an answer to this question:

I have a PostgreSQL table that is staged the following way:

```
Start Date | End Date   |  Name   | Team
-----------+------------+---------+------
2017-10-01 | 2017-10-10 | Person  |   1
```

And what I would like to is have each row a day between the start date and end date with the corresponding name and team of the person:

```
   Date     |  Name   |  Team
------------+---------+-------
2017-10-01  | Person  |   1
------------+---------+-------
2017-10-02  | Person  |   1
------------+---------+-------
2017-10-03  | Person  |   1
```

Is it even possible to do this with PostgreSQL? I'm currently running PostgreSQL 9.3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `generate_series()` for that:

```
select t.dt::date, p.name, p.team
from person p, generate_series(p.start_date, p.end_date, interval '1' day) as t(dt)
order by t.dt::date;
```

I don't have 9.3 around any more, but I think that should also work with that old version.